# How to touch/click row at position in arraylist with customadapter and perform action

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have `ListView` with a custom `Adapter` which includes 2 texts and one button. When I touch any row, it plays an mp3 sound by using `convertView.setOnClickListener` and highlights the row using the following.

```
convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray)
```

But what I exactly need it, when the sound finishes, It should automatically select and highlight the next row and play another sound using `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener`.

I have already tried with the following.

```
- listView.setSelection(position+1);
- listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter().getView(position+1, null, null),position+1,listView.getAdapter().getItemId(position+1));
- listView.setItemChecked(position+1,true);
```

By using this, I expect it should play programmatically clicking the next row, highlight it and play the sound. But nothing happens with all these codes except, it scrolls to that particular row.

Here is my code from CustomAdapter Class:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_cell,null);
        TextView aText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aText);
        TextView bText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bText);
        cButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cButton);



        aText.setText(aTextArray.get(position));
        bText.setText(bTextArray.get(position));

    convertView.setFocusable(false);
        final View finalConvertView1 = convertView;

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
     readingList.setSelection(position);

                finalConvertView1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
    try {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource("mp3link"));
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(ReadingActivity.this);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            listView.setSelection(position+1);
                            listView.performItemClick(
                                    readingList.getAdapter().getView(position+1, null, null),
                                    position+1,
                                    readingList.getAdapter().getItemId(position+1));
    //listView.setItemChecked(position+1,true);
    //listView.setSelection(position+1);

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
      @Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: post your code plz!

Comment: First of all, I would highly recommend that you should use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:
you create a falg isHighlight in arrayListData, using highlishts the row.
When the sound finishs you change arrayListData.get(position+1).isHighlisht = true
then you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the click action to the item in your `ListView`, you might consider keeping a variable to indicate which item is playing now. When an item is finished playing, set the next element of the array as playing by incrementing the variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter. Based on the value from that variable, change your UI elements accordingly. Here is a pseudo-code on how you should proceed.

Take an array like the following.

```
private int playingNow = 0; // Initialize this with zero. At first none is being played
```

Then on clicking an item, set the corresponding array element to `1` which indicates the item is playing now. Here's a sample function for your adapter.

```
private void playSound(int position) {
    // Start playing the sound here
    // And modify the variable
    playingNow = position;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now in your `getView`, modify the views based on the indicator that you have.

```
if(position == playingNow) setBackgroundColorToSelected();
else setBackgroundColorToNormal();
```

And once you are finished with playing one item, adjust the value of the variable accordingly.

```
private void playNext() {
    if(playingNow + 1 == yourItems.size()) playingNow = 0; // I guess you might want to play the first song when it reaches the end of the list
    else playingNow++;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your valuabe answer, can you just have a look on my updated question?

Comment: I think you need to check what the `getItem`, `getView`, `getCount` functions do in your custom adapter implementation.